# deploy web application using zappa

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, zappa

I was following the steps here: https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa to try to deploy my web app to AWS.

My app is using flask as server side and it also uses flask to host client-side JavaScript, html and css files. I can successfully host it on my local machine and on a server machine (I used `host="0.0.0.0"` on the server and I also specified a port number).

All I need to do is to run `python my_app.py`. The client side sends requests to the server and the server will respond.

I tried to deploy with `zappa`, but the page loads to an empty one. I'm not sure where I did wrong. One thing is that there are external libraries needed for my python program, how do I install it when I deploy it to my AWS lambda?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to install your external libraries locally first, and then Zappa will take care of uploading them as part of the zip file.

In other words:

- `virtualenv my_venv`
- `source my_venv/bin/activate`
- `pip install zappa flask django etc`
- then run a local webserver to test that your app works, e.g. `flask run`
- `zappa init`
- `zappa deploy dev` OR `zappa update dev` (if you've already run `deploy`)